# Looking for a good pattern to implement View adapters for objects, in Java/JSP

Tags: java, design-patterns

this is more a design question. Suppose you have many beans A, B, C.... Then you have a class that creates, say, tables out of beans. You need something that tells this class which properties of those beans to display, what names give to the columns and other rendering properties. I don't want to hardwire this in the class for each bean class, so I was thinking of giving the beans a common interface like TableAdapterProvider, that would come out with a class that gives all instructions to the rendering class. The problem is that I can't make an interface method static in Java. And this doesn't seem very clean for a number of reasons... for example to create an empty table I have to allocate a bean and then call the interface method TableAdapterProvider to retrieve the "rendering" class.

I thought of creating a factory like `TableAdapterFactory(Class beanClass)` that returns the correct TableAdapter for each bean class without instanting any. Anyway I have to update this factory for every bean I create.

Another solution could be use special naming conventions, for example if a bean name is Apple, then AppleTableRenderer will be the renderer. I can scan a package in search of this when the TableRenderer starts so the associations are done automatically.

Do you know of a better pattern? What do you think of my approaches?

For the future, is there a good book with recipes like these to use in web apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that any bean (A, B, C..) that needs to be displayed as a HTML table (by some kind of `TableRenderer`) should implement an interface that provides the renderer with the required information. The likely interface methods would get the columns headers and the table data. Maybe also one for table style, but that is a bit subjective.

With this in mind you might have;

```
public interface Renderable
{
  public List<String> getHeaders();
  public List<List<String>> getData();
}

public class A implements Renderable
{
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public List<String> getHeaders()
  {
    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
    headers.add("Name");
    headers.add("Age");
    return list;
  }

  public List<List<String>> getData()
  {
    List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<List<String>();
    List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
    row.add(name);
    row.add(String.valueOf(age));
    data.add(row);
    return data;
  }

  //getters and setters

}
```

It's then pretty trivial to write your `TableRenderer`;

```
public class TableRenderer
{
  public String render(Renderable r)
  {
     //draw a HTML table
     //draw table headers from r.getHeaders()
     //draw table rows from r.getData()
  }
}
```

Note that instead of writing a `TableRenderer` class you might want to use the JSTL `<c:forEach>` syntax, which is a more standard approach.

Comment: That's exactly what I started to do.... what I don't like is that is bound to an instance of a bean as it is not static methods. I would avoid this honestly

Comment: @gotch4 what is wrong with binding it to an instance of a bean? It doesn't make sense to render a bean if there's no instance; there'd be nothing to render! If you want to show an empty table (ie just headers) to indicate the *absence* of a bean then you could simply instantiate a new instance and call `getHeaders()`.

Comment: you may be right, seems not be other solution than this one. :) tnx

Answer (score 0):

you could use an abstract class.

implement chosen common methods in the abstract class

implement class specific method within each class.

added code.

to generate the table you need to call generateTable method with the paremeter generated by the processBean methhod

```
public abstract class Parent {
    /**
     * This method generates table from common input
     * @param commonTableMaterial
     * @return
     */
    private String generateTable(String commonTableMaterial ){
        return commonTableMaterial+"table me";
    }

    /**
     * This method is class specific - generating needed input to table
     * @return
     */
    abstract protected String processBean() ;

}

public class ChildA extends Parent {

    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName ;
    private String hiddenName ;

    @Override
    protected String processBean() {

        return firstName +lastName ;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was doing... Anyway what I wanted was to use static methods.... that's why my question. Seems there is no other solution anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a combination. Keep the factory, that's a good pattern for your task: a factory that creates the correct renderer for a given bean.

But let the factory try to find the renderer - either by scanning a certain package or by reading the renderer classname from a configuration file.

And if the factory can't find a renderer, it could use a default renderer that simply reflects the bean class and creates cells for all fields.